# SQL Server Rename Data Folder

Tags: t-sql

I lost several days worth of SQL data in mdf and ldf files on my server stored at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Server\MSSQL11.MyServer\MSSQL\DATA.

I have uploaded files with the missing data to a folder called DATA_NEW in the same path.

I would like to test the Restored Data by renaming my current DATA folder to DATA_OLD and then renaming the DATA_NEW folder to DATA so that my database points to the Restored Data.

Is this a good way of verifying that the renamed data folder contains the valid data - with an option to revert back to the data in the folder named DATA_OLD?

Does anyone know of any reasons that I should not proceed with this approach?

Thanks very much, 
Mark D

Comment: It depends on if you're going to keep any changes after the last backup. If so, I'd restore the database backup and then you can use the Data Comparison In Visual Studio to either generate the scripts or one click update.

Comment: Thanks aduguid. We decided to create a new database and point it to the DATA_NEW folder - which seems to have worked well for our purposes.